# can we increase the storage limit of web-sql For apple ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, mobile-safari, web-sql

I'm creating offline application with phonegap and HTML5. for that i m using Web-SQL database. and **i have bunch of images around 1500.**
problem is i cant download it every time so i m converting the images in base64 code and save into the Web-SQL database table and using it. So the issue is with iPad only because my image converted code size is around 60 MB . because of that 'm using in it my personal computer or Android phone its working fine because there have no limitation of web SQL database size . but in iPad there is Fixed 50 MB of limitation of the  Web-SQL database. So the images could not be stored in web sql database for ipad .

is there any way or possible to increase the size of web-SQL database

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".